# Mocking an inner require statement in Typescript constructor

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, jestjs

I know this is kind of a weird question, but I would like to mock an inner `require();` statement in a constructor. This is my test file:

```
import { PiControl } from "../pi";

describe("PiControl", () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
        this.piControl = new PiControl();
    });

    it("Should initialise the control and call the board ready event.", () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });

});
```

As you can see below, I'm instantiating the class `PiControl` and when I run my test and make an instance of the PiControl.

```
export class PiControl extends BaseControl {

    public board: any;
    constructor() {
        super();
        // No idea if this can be mocked, but I would like to.
        const Raspi = require("raspi-io");
        const five = require("johnny-five");
        const board = new five.Board({
            io: new Raspi({ enableSoftPwm: true }),
        });
        this.board = board;
    }

    public loadControl(): void {
        this.board.on("ready", this.setupMotors);
    }

}
```

As you can see below, that is what the test outputs. It will call the original library (which is supposed to run on a Raspberry PI) and tries to run it on my development machine.

Question: is there a way to workaround this issue?

For what it's worth, I'm testing the whole application using Jest (almost out-of-the-box config).

[image: Here is the test output]

Comment: Why not use dependency injection?

Comment: Valid question. I tried that before but couldn't mock injected dependencies either. Probably due to my lack of knowledge of TypeScript. The code worked this way in a NodeJS application and I grabbed the sources from DefinitelyTyped, but events on the board wouldn't throw so I removed TypeScript specific code for raspi-io and johnny-five and did it the old-fashioned way. Besides, I was thinking that I could workaround this issue by putting the code in `loadControl()` and mock that one.. Maybe I put this question up to early.